# How to set default value of parameter input control in Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with my parameter who are an input control in Ireport. My parameter is a boolean. And I try to set a default value because I need to modify my sql request with parameter. By example if my parameter is true so I put on my request a like with an other parameters else I put nothing. But my problem is my parameters is always true or false and not the value I define in default value.

This is my try with default value of my parameter:

```
$P{choix_repere_depart}=="true" 
? " AND d.cellule like '%$P{mot_cle}%'" 
: " "
```

And this my sql request:

```
SELECT
     r.designation as designation,
     l.nom as nom,
     e.gare as gare,
     b.intitule as intitule,
     a.code_mire as code_mire,
     af.codegmao as codegmaoAF,
     ap.codegmao as codegmaoAP,
     d.cellule as repere,
     d.observation as observation,
     m.appareil as appareil
FROM
      armoireprincipale ap
LEFT JOIN armoire a ON a.idbranchement = ap.idbranchement
LEFT JOIN armoirefille af ON af.idbranchement = a.idbranchement
LEFT JOIN branchement b ON b.idbranchement = a.idbranchement
LEFT JOIN ligne l ON l.id_ligne = b.id_ligne
LEFT JOIN reseau r ON r.id_reseau = l.id_reseau
LEFT JOIN edifice e ON e.indic = b.indic
LEFT JOIN depart d ON d.idbranchement = a.idbranchement
LEFT JOIN materiel m ON m.id_materiel = d.id_materiel
WHERE  a.idbranchement IN (SELECT b.idbranchement
            FROM branchement b0
            LEFT JOIN cable c ON c.idbranchement = b0.idbranchement
            LEFT JOIN cable_depart cb ON cb.id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN depart d0 ON d0.iddepart = cb.iddepart
            LEFT JOIN armoire a0 ON a0.idbranchement = d0.idbranchement
            LEFT JOIN armoireprincipale ap0 ON ap0.idbranchement = a0.idbranchement
            WHERE ap0.ug_pef= $P{id_pef}
) $P{choix_repere_depart};
```

So I need help to understand what is wrong on my report. If someone has an idea please help me!!! Thank!!

Comment: You should post the snippet with `$P{choix_repere_depart}` declaration

Comment: Did you try epression like this: `$P{choix_repere_depart} ? " AND d.cellule like '%$P!{mot_cle}%'" : " "`?